# Why are the array elements changed after sort,C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

The elements of the array changed, and became some numbers which are never being input.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1000

int cmp(int a, int b)
 {
  return a>b;
 }

void sort(int *data, int n, int (*cmp)(int, int))
{
 for (;n>1;n--)
{
  int i_max = 0;
  for(int i = 1;i<n;i++)
   if(cmp(data[i],data[i_max])) i_max = i;

 int temp = data[i_max];
 data[i_max] = data[n-1];
 data[n-1] = temp;
 }
}


int main()
{
 int data[MAX_SIZE] , n;
 scanf("%d",&n);
 for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
 {
    int m;
    puts("*****************");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    for(int j = 0 ; j < m ; j++)
        scanf("%d",data+j);
    sort(data, m, cmp);
    puts("after sorting:");
    for(int j = 0 ; j < m ; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",data[j]);
    }
    puts("\n*****************");
}

return 0;
}
```

input:

```
5
5
12
346
5676434535
765654543596
3543456
6
5783945
5293
237894
273894
73
237482
4
27895
719287349723947
1
34
7
3472893
74897598347
757
178
579875498234
129
84
5
420938
23
837485
279
29871
```

output:

```
*****************
after sorting:
12 346 3543456 1150364908 1381467239
(the last two numbers were never input before, and the former number disappeared) 
*****************
*****************
after sorting:
73 5293 237482 237894 273894 5783945 
*****************
*****************
after sorting:
1 34 27895 586728235 
*****************
*****************
after sorting:
84 129 178 757 3472893 54913274 1883154315 
*****************
```

Comment: Did you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: Check if your array indexes don't go out of bounds. Accessing an array with out of bounds indexes is undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @MichaelWalz The indexes look fine to me.

Comment: What does sorting have to do with it? What output do you get without `sort()`? Please see [mcve].

Comment: @melpomene that was just a wild guess without even looking at the code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Then what is "*array indexes start at 0, not at 1 !!*" all about? If you didn't even look at the code, why bother writing this comment (using a double exclamation mark, no less)?

Comment: @melpomene comment deleted. But this is what usually happens

Comment: sorry for this, thanks for all your suggestions!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 3):

The input you provide is not fitting into `int`. For example `765654543596` (hex `B244912CEC`) is exceeding 32 bits, which is probably your `int` width. If you truncate it to 32 bits you will see exactly the mysterious `1150364908` (hex `44912CEC`) you see in the output.

Answer (score 0):

your program is actually correct. except you are feeding in more than an `int` can contain. try the program with values not grater `>` than **2147483647** unless you want to change the datatype from `int` to possibly `unsigned int`. but still there are limits to both maximum values.